# AngulaJS ng bind not working - Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am attempting to set value for span through AngularJS ng-bind when validate name. I have tried in many ways 
but unfortunately its not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="modalCtrl as data">

    <input id="name" ng-model="data.name"
       type="text" ng-blur="validateName(this.data)" />
    <span ng-bind="data.name.errMsg"></span>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.validateName=function(obj){
    var name = obj.name;
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\@\&\%\*\$\>\<\\[\\]\,\(\)\_\'\;\ \:\\-\\.]+$");
    if(name != undefined && name != null && name.length < 3){
        obj.name.errMsg = "Please enter minimum 3 characters in Name";
        //$scope.name.errMsg = "Please enter minimum 3 characters in Name"
        // TypeError: Cannot set property 'errMsg' of undefined
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing validateName(this.data) with validateName(data) ? the this.data doesn't seem correct. You can also console.log("validateName",obj) inside your function to find out in the web console what the data being passed in actually is.

Comment: obj.name >> Its give correct name whatever i input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the errMsg on the correct scope variable.

Try it like this

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("modalCtrl",function(){
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.nameObj = {};
ctrl.nameObj.name= "sss";

ctrl.validateName=function(){
    var name = ctrl.nameObj.name;
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\@\&\%\*\$\>\<\\[\\]\,\(\)\_\'\;\ \:\\-\\.]+$");
    if(name != undefined && name != null && name.length < 3){
        ctrl.nameObj.errMsg = "Please enter minimum 3 characters in Name"
        // TypeError: Cannot set property 'errMsg' of undefined
    } else { ctrl.nameObj.errMsg = "";}
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="modalCtrl as data">

    <input id="name" ng-model="data.nameObj.name"
       type="text" ng-blur="data.validateName()" />
    <span ng-bind="data.nameObj.errMsg"></span>
    {{data.nameObj.errMsg}}

</div>
```

Comment: why we need to declare ctrl.nameObj = {}; in controller. can you please explain

Comment: @deadend I added it because i think you need an object which contains the data about the name property. In your example, you set the ng-model to data.name but later set the data.name.errorMsg..This is confusing as the ng-model of your input tag should be text, not an object. So, I think you need to contain both the name and the errorMsg connected to the name in one object. Then your ng-model will be against the data.nameObj.name and the errorMsg data.nameObj.errorMsg. This is much clearer and you don't break the ng-model of the input tag

Comment: @ Marcus.. Noted & Thanks for your help.

Comment: @deadend Np :) please accept answer if it was to any help

Answer (score 1):

obj.name would a string not an object. You cannot set property of string type. You can set the obj as follow.

```
obj = [{name:'name', errMsg:'error message here'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="modalCtrl as data">

    <input id="name" ng-model="data.name"
       type="text" ng-blur="validateName(this.data)" />
    <span ng-bind="data.errMsg"></span> // data.errMsg instead of data.name.errMsg

</div>


$scope.validateName=function(obj){
    var name = obj.name;
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\@\&\%\*\$\>\<\\[\\]\,\(\)\_\'\;\ \:\\-\\.]+$");
    if(name != undefined && name != null && name.length < 3){
        obj.errMsg = "Please enter minimum 3 characters in Name"; 
        //obj.errMsg instead of obj.name.errMsg
    }
};
```

Comment: Its working.. Can you please say me why data.name.errMsg is now working

Comment: when you are binding obj.name to your input then your object was like {name : "abc"}

so it will bind to your input value but you are binding your error msg to that object like obj.name.errMsg = "validation msg" so your object looks like 
{ name :{ errrMsg : "Validation Msg"}}. So after validating your textbox value will be like "[object]" because you are now binding value to whole json object. that is why it was not working. You need to bind text box value to any string type value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below code, Also please check [this plunker link](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/YLwhZIJXkgQnErzc) for working example of your given scenario.

**Template:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as data">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <input id="name" ng-model="data.name" type="text" ng-blur="validateName(this.data)" /><br/>
        <span ng-bind="data.errMsg"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.validateName=function(obj){
    var name = obj.name;
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\@\&\%\*\$\>\<\\[\\]\,\(\)\_\'\;\ \:\\-\\.]+$");
    if(name != undefined && name != null && name.length < 3){
        obj.errMsg = "Please enter minimum 3 characters in Name";
    } else obj.errMsg = '';
};
```